# Change font-size of the values in Debug in Rider ide

Tags: ide, settings, font-size, jetbrains-ide, rider

Is it possible to change the font-size of the values in Debug in Rider ide?

After going to Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> UI Options -> Override default fonts by and changing the font-size here I change the font-size of some parts of ide, but not all of them.

For instance the font-size of values data in Debug is not updated. So, how could I update the font-size for the values in Debug?

[image]

Thank you.